# Capture Windows Authentication(Credentials), using 2 separate projects. React Front-End & .NET Core Back-End

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an internal project for my company. I need to capture the user windows credentials when they first arrive on the website, in my API call on the front end react app. I am currently using Axios but I do not mind switching to fetch statements if the makes the process easier. The problem is that the front end and back end projects are 2 separate projects with their own repositories and hosted one 2 different ports. We are using an IIS server to host the site.

The hard part is that because the back end and front end are 2 separate projects it is hard to pass the windows credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to send request to Windows authenticationweb api. You just need set your client side send the request with the local credentials by using [fetch](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) method.

Notice: The react could also use ajax fetch method.

About how to use fetch api include the local user credentials, you could refer to below codes:

```
    fetch("http://localhost:6099/api/Values", {
        method: 'Get',
        credentials: 'include'
    }).then(function (data) {
        // Here you get the data to modify as you please
        document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = data;
    })
```

Comment: Do you know what they syntax is to also include cors in the header of the API request.

Comment: As far as I know, the fetch api has the options that could include the cors mode. Like: `no-cors, *cors, same-origin`. Detials, you could refer to this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Answer (score 0):

We have used proxy for this purpose.

This is really cool article [how authorization headers can be sent through proxy](https://www.sensibledev.com/reactjs-webpack-and-asp-net-standard/#fixing-invalid-authentication-headers).

So it is necessary:

1. add some proxy file
2. install dependency `agentkeepalive`

   ```
   npm install -D agentkeepalive
   ```

The complete proxy file looks like this:

```
// development config
const package = require('../../package.json')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const commonConfig = require('./common')
const agent = require('agentkeepalive')

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => merge(commonConfig(argv), {
        mode: 'development',
        entry: [
            'react-hot-loader/patch',
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3030',
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
            './index.tsx', // the entry point of our app
        ],
        devServer: {
            port: 3030,
            hot: true, // enable HMR on the server
            historyApiFallback: true,
            proxy: {
                '/api/*': {
                    target: argv.env.mock ? '' : 'https://localhost:8800/',
                    secure: false,
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    agent: new agent.HttpsAgent({
                        maxSockets: 100,
                        keepAlive: true,
                        maxFreeSockets: 10,
                        keepAliveMsecs: 100000,
                        timeout: 6000000,
                        freeSocketTimeout: 90000, // free socket keepalive for 90 seconds
                    }),
                    onProxyRes: (proxyRes) => {
                        var key = 'www-authenticate'
                        proxyRes.headers[key] =
                            proxyRes.headers[key] && proxyRes.headers[key].split(',')
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), // enable HMR globally
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.appVersion': JSON.stringify(package.version),
                'process.env.isMockMode': JSON.stringify(argv?.env?.mock),
                'process.env.isDevelopment': true,
            }),
        ],
    })
```